# How to get user input date in PHP to use in the where clause of a PostgreSQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have a query in which the where clause is

```
WHERE (NOW()::DATE - coalesce(orders.delivery_date::DATE, NOW()::DATE)) <= 30
```

and this works well for pulling orders where the delivery date occurred less than a month from the current date. However, I need the flexibility of taking user input for a date rather than always using the current date.

When the user inputs the date then my php code gets the input and returns it in this format if I echo it out

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

If I give the user input date a veriable name like

```
$user_date
```

Then I need an SQL query for

```
WHERE ($user_date::DATE - coalesce(orders.delivery_date::DATE, $user_date::DATE)) <= 30
```

but I'm not figuring out how to format that PHP variable for the user input date for the query to work. Basically, I need to use $user_date rather than NOW(). Any advice? FYI, the field type for delivery date is timestamp without time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You should break up the user input using explode.

```
 $date = explode("/", $user_date);
```

Then you need to put the array items back together in the order that is the same as your database

```
$date = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the date timestamp and pass it as an integer (passing an integer makes it easier to prevent sql injection). On the postgres side I would convert the int back to timestamp:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('15-04-2017');
```

---

```
timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + $timestamp  * INTERVAL '1 second'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that is pulling from the database like it should

```
$sql_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($user_date));
```

and then for the WHERE clause in my SQL

```
WHERE ('$sql_date'::DATE - coalesce(orders.delivery_date::DATE, '$sql_date'::DATE)) <= 30
```